# Using ElectronJS, is there a way to run a Java applet (.jar) in the window?

Tags: javascript, java, electron, applet

I'm working on a project for a friend, and it involves inserting a Java applet into an Electron HTML document for the user to interact with. Is there a way to do this?

I've already tried using [node-jre](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-jre) to run it, and I am able to output the results into the console which is fine, but that doesn't give me an applet. I'm not too familiar with Java, but I understand some concepts of it.

Here's what I have using node-jre:

```
var output = jre.spawnSync(['client.jar']);

  console.log(output);
```

I need the result to be `<applet archive="file.jar"></applet>` in the HTML file the user will view.

Answer (score 3):

No, this isn't possible.

In the past, embedding a Java applet in a web page (or other web view) required the Java NPAPI plugin to be installed. [This plugin was discontinued in Java 9](https://www.java.com/en/download/faq/jdk9_plugin.xml), and [browser engines no longer support NPAPI plugins](https://blog.chromium.org/2013/09/saying-goodbye-to-our-old-friend-npapi.html), so there is no way to do this.

You will need to run your Java applet as a standalone application, or rewrite it in Javascript to run within an Electron app.